# Day trading definition

Tags: investing

When I read the rules I get a little confused regarding the term "same stock in same trading day". If I buy 10 stocks on Monday and sell the same on Tuesday (different trading day) would I be considered a day trader?

Comment: What rules, where?

Answer (score 2):

"If I buy 10 stocks on Monday and sell the same on Tuesday (different trading day) would I be considered a day trader?"

No.

It only counts  if you buy something and then sell that same something during the same trading session. And that counter only lasts for 5 days, things that happened outside of that time period get removed from the counter.

If the counter reaches a number (three to five, depending on the broker), then you are labelled as a pattern day trader, and will have your trading capabilities severely restricted unless you have an account size greater than $25,000

Comment: The Pattern Day Trader rule  limitation is not determined by brokers.  It's an SEC rule that allows only  3 day trades in a rolling five  business day period in a margin account, provided the number of day trades are more than six percent of the customer's total trading activity for that same five-day period.   There is no limit to how many day trades you can make in a cash account as long as you are using settled funds.